# How to render datatable in playframework on click on the hyperlink which was present on the left side nav

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I am developing one web application using play framework, i want to display data in grid format using id which will get by click on the links on the nav which is present on left hand side(similar to zentasks sample application which was provided by play framework).

I am able to render list of data in the form of href's on the left hand side navigator. But when i click on any item it's not rendering the corresponding view.

I followed the zentasks example which they have given. In zentask sample i didn't understand how they are rendering the body by click on the projects which are present on the nav.

can anybody please share how can i achieve the above functionality in play framework:

I have Main.scala.html, i have Nav and Section parts as below:

```
<h4 class="dashboard"><a href="#/">Locate Equipment</a></h4>
        <ul id="projects">
            <li data-group="equipment groups">
                <span class="toggle"></span>
                <h4 class="groupName">Equipment Groups</h4>
                <span class="loader">Loading</span>                
                <ul style="height: 500px; overflow: auto">                      
                        @equipmentgroups.map{ task=>    
                        <li data-project="@task.id">                   
                            <a class="name" href="#@routes.EquipmentGroups.search(task.id)">@task.name</a>
                             <span class="loader">Loading</span> </li>}                                                 
                </ul>       
            </li>              
    </nav>
    <section id="main">
        @body
    </section>
```

`
and dashboard.scala.html is as below:

```
@(favorite:List[Favorite],equipmentGroup:List[EquipmentGroup],user: User)
@main(favorite,equipmentGroup,user){    
<header>
    <hgroup>
        <h1>Dashboard</h1>            
    </hgroup>
</header>    
<article  class="tasks">        
        <div class="folder" >
            <header>
                <h3><a href="#">Equipment Group</a></h3>                   
                               </header>                                 
        </div>    
</article>
```

}

On Click on the left hand side of the link i want to show that equipment name in the right hand side, i added the Equipment.scala.html in views.EquipmentGroups folder.

    `@( title: String)
    <h4> This is @title</h4>`

This is my application.java:
`
    public class Application extends Controller {

```
public static class Login {
    public String username;
    public String password;

    public String validate() {
        if (User.authenticate(username, password) == null) {
            return "Invalid user or password";
        }
        return null;
    }
}
public static Result list() {
    System.out.println(request().username());
    return ok(dashboard.render(Favorite.GetFavorite(),
            EquipmentGroup.GetEquipmentGroup(),
            User.GetUser(session().get("username"))));
}

public static Result login() {
    return ok(login.render(form(Login.class)));
}

public static Result logout() {
    session().clear();
    flash("success", "You've been logged out");
    return redirect(routes.Application.login());
}

public static Result authenticate() {
    Form<Login> loginForm = form(Login.class).bindFromRequest();
    if (loginForm.hasErrors()) {
        return badRequest(login.render(loginForm));
    } else {
        session("username", loginForm.get().username);
        return redirect(routes.Application.list());
    }
}

public static Result javascriptRoutes() {
    response().setContentType("text/javascript");
    return ok(
        Routes.javascriptRouter("jsRoutes",
                controllers.routes.javascript.EquipmentGroups.search()
                )
        );
}`
```

i haven't written any javascripts.

Please let me know if i need to give any more info.

Comment: Please show your code to let the community reproduce your problem. Browser, Play Version, Java/Scala are also unclear.

Comment: I updated my question with code, to answer your question i am using chrome browser, playversion is 2.0.4 with java.

Comment: Thank you, that's better now. But too much noise (authentication does not have anything to do with the problem?) and code for the models and the EquipmentGroups is missing. Your problem is, you click on one side of a link and on the loaded page on the side should be the title corresponding to the clicked link?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure (I havent tried it), but following seems suspitious to me:

In Main.scala.html, task navigation links seems to be invalid, I think you have one unwanted char at the beginning of each link:

```
<a class="name" href="#@routes.EquipmentGroups.search(task.id)">@task.name</a>
                      ^
                      |
                      This hash char seems to be the problem, remove it
```

If this hash is not the problem, can anyone explain me what is it's purpose? ;)